# Location objects near routelines

Tags: c#, algorithm, xaml, microsoft-metro, maps

I'm coding a metro app using xaml and c#

Currently I have a large set of data (~700) which represent locations on a map in the form of pushpins. I am currently attempting to only display the pushpins near a routeline which has been made between two points on the map. The pushpins and the routeline are drawn on the map using latitude and longitude coordinates. However they do not exactly match with each other and are usually only nearby. I was wondering if there is a way to filter down the visible pushpins based on proximity to the routeline that is drawn. Thank you. I will provide further information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you can find some algorithms related to distance calculation.

Comment: Thanks, the haversine formula looks promising

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what storage strategy you are using. But if you happen to be using SQL Server, the methods to calculate what you are wanting are built right in. It's actually awesome.

If you are interested, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929145.aspx

Comment: I'm currently using http requests with c# to get the location coordinates, since the data set is so small I just store it locally. Do you know any examples online that I can look at, I've just started learning sql but if this method can cut down on processing time then it would be ideal.

Comment: Offloading to a SQL in the cloud will cut down on processing time every single time. If you can handle always-connected, then cloud processing is the way all future apps will be handling complex processing.

Comment: okay, I will start configuring my azure sql database and post the results. thanks for the help.